# Mongoose single embedded sub-document default

Tags: mongoose

Mongoose created a new single sub-document feature ([documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#single-embedded) and [feature request](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/585)) in version 4.2.7 allowing for a single embedded sub document schema which behaves they way one-to-many sub documents behave.

What is the best way to create a default single sub-doc upon parent save?

```
var UserPermisssionsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    siteAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    }
});

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  fname: String,
  lname: String,
  permissions: UserPermisssionsSchema 
});
```

I would like the `permissions` field to be created with default values when the parent user document is created.

This does not work:

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  fname: String,
  lname: String,
  permissions: {
    type: UserPermisssionsSchema ,
    default: UserPermisssionsSchema
  }
});
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Please try this one

```
var PerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    siteAdmin: {type: Boolean, default: false}
  }); 

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  fname: String,
  lname: String,
  permissions: { type: PerSchema, default: () => ({}) },
});
```

Test it with `Mongoose v4.4.3`

```
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

function setUser() {
    var u = new User({
        fname: 'asa',
        lname: 'dddd'
    });

    u.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            console.log('save user successfully');
    });
}
```

Result is

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("56c68321a548be98198ebb71"), 
  "fname" : "asa", 
  "lname" : "dddd", 
  "permissions" : {
       "_id" : ObjectId("56c68321a548be98198ebb70"), 
       "siteAdmin" : false
       },
   "__v" : 0
}
```

---

If you want the default value of `permissions` is `{}`. Please try it as below

```
var PerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    siteAdmin: {type: Boolean}
}, {_id: false}); 

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    fname: String,
    lname: String,
    permissions: { type: PerSchema, required: true, default: {} },
});
```

Test

```
function setUser() {
    var u = new User({
        fname: 'asa',
        lname: 'dddd'
    });

    u.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            console.log('save user successfully');
    });
}
```

Result is

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c687427191d54021875fb1"), 
  "fname" : "asa", 
  "lname" : "dddd",
  "permissions" : {  }, 
  "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: @steampowered, I test it and show the result in my answer, please let me know if I miss something...

Comment: I was using `4.2.7` when I had the error, but now when I upgrade to 4.4.3 it works!

Comment: Is there any reason why you defined `PerSchema` as a **new** `mongoose.Schema` and `UserSchema` as simply `mongoose.Schema`?

Comment: Please do not set the `default` to be a schema instance. `default: PerSchema` is wrong and throws an error in more recent versions of Mongoose. Use `default: () => ({})` instead.

Answer (score 21):

Mongoose maintainer here, I'd recommend this:

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  fname: String,
  lname: String,
  permissions: 
    type: UserPermisssionsSchema ,
    default: () => ({}),
  }
});
```

This will make `permissions` default to an empty object, with respect to any defaults the `UserPermissionsSchema` might have. If you set `default` to `UserPermisssionsSchema` you might get some bad behavior if one of your properties happens to overlap with a mongoose schema method.

Comment: what if instead of degining the schema externally we are using type:Object and just defining the subdocument embedded in the permissions field, how could you set default values?

Comment: the year is 2022, the `default: () => ({})` trick is still a live saver!

Comment: @Pavel'PK'Kaminsky it's ain't a trick, mongoose calls `() => ({})` and returns `{}`. `() => {}` this returns **undefined** unlike `() => ({})`. Because first is interpretated as block-statement and second one as expression

Comment: Its 2023, and this ls still relevant

Answer (score 1):

#### Mongoose single embedded sub-document default

```
var UserPermisssionsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    siteAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    }
});

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  fname: String,
  lname: String,
  permissions: 
    type: UserPermisssionsSchema,
    default: () => ({}),
})
```

#### Mongoose multiple(Array) embedded sub-document default

```
var UserPermisssionsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    siteAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    }
});

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  fname: String,
  lname: String,
  permissions: 
    type: [UserPermisssionsSchema],
    default: () => ([]),
})
```

Comment: `default: () => ({})` seems to work for both Array and single sub-document default